# I am writing a simple code to ask someone's name, their teacher's name and then average out their last 4 test scores and display a certain message

Tags: python, function, return, typeerror

```
def user_name():
  ask_name = str(input("Enter your name: "))
  return ask_name

def print_greeting(ask_name):
  str(print("Your name is {0}.".format(ask_name)))

ask_name = user_name()
print_greeting(ask_name)

def teacher_name():
  ask_teacher_name = str(input("What is the name of your computer science teacher?: "))
  return ask_teacher_name

def print_teacher_greeting(ask_teacher_name):
  str(print("Your computer science teacher's name is {0}.".format(ask_teacher_name)))

ask_teacher_name = teacher_name()
print_teacher_greeting(ask_teacher_name)
```

Not sure but I think the above lines are fine and don't have anything to do with the problem but it is something to do with how I've phrased the determine_outcome function.

```
def calc_average( score1, score2, score3, score4, ):
  average = ( score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 ) / 4
  return average

def ask_score():
  score1 = float(input( "Please enter score 1: "))
  score2 = float(input( "Please enter score 2: "))
  score3 = float(input( "Please enter score 3: "))
  score4 = float(input( "Please enter score 4: "))

  return score1, score2, score3, score4

def determine_outcome(user_score):
  if(user_score <=8 ):
    print("Well done {0}, your average score was {1}. {2} would be proud of you.".format(str(print_greeting), str(ask_score), str(print_teacher_greeting)))
  elif(user_score >= 6 < 8):
    print("A good effort, {0}, your average was {1}. {2} thinks you should check your work more carefully.".format(str(print_greeting), str(ask_score), str(print_teacher_greeting)))
  elif(user_score <=5 ):
    print("{0}, this is quite poor. Your average was only {1}. {2} has asked you to try harder please.".format(str(print_greeting), str(ask_score), str(print_teacher_greeting)))

def main():
  score1, score2, score3, score4 = ask_score()
  determine_outcome(ask_score)

main()

#if(user_score <=8 ):
#TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'
```

This is always the result and I don't know where I have gone wrong
I am quite new to coding so it might be an obvious mistake but I can't see anything wrong at the moment.

Comment: `determine_outcome(ask_score)` is passing the function `ask_score` to the function `determine_outcome`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to pass the average score of the student to the `determine_outcome()` function in `main()`, your `main()` should be as follows:

```
def main():
  score1, score2, score3, score4 = ask_score()
  determine_outcome(calc_average(score1, score2, score3, score4))
```

Also you have to change your `determine_outcome()` function as it does not recognize `ask_score`. Change it to `user_score` and it would work.

You also have to change the print_greeting() and print_teacher_greeting() function and return the str:

```
def print_greeting(ask_name):
  return str("Your name is {0}.".format(ask_name))

def print_teacher_greeting(ask_teacher_name):
  return str("Your computer science teacher's name is {0}.".format(ask_teacher_name))
```

I would personally suggest you to use f-string:

```
def print_greeting(ask_name):
  return f"Your name is {ask_name}."

def print_teacher_greeting(ask_teacher_name):
  return f"Your computer science teacher's name is {ask_teacher_name}."
```

Editing my answer further, change the function as given below:

```
def determine_outcome(user_score):
  if(user_score <=8 ):
    print("Well done {0}, your average score was {1}. {2} would be proud of you.".format(print_greeting(ask_name), str(user_score), print_teacher_greeting(ask_teacher_name)))
  elif(user_score >= 6 < 8):
    print("A good effort, {0}, your average was {1}. {2} thinks you should check your work more carefully.".format(print_greeting(ask_name), str(user_score), print_teacher_greeting(ask_teacher_name)))
  elif(user_score <=5 ):
    print("{0}, this is quite poor. Your average was only {1}. {2} has asked you to try harder please.".format(print_greeting(ask_name), str(user_score), print_teacher_greeting(ask_teacher_name)))
```

Comment: I have implemented your ideas and I still get:


Well done <function print_greeting at 0x000001E6560DB820>, your average score was <function ask_score at 0x000001E6560DBA60>. <function print_teacher_greeting at 0x000001E6560DB940> would be proud of you.

Comment: Yeah I have changed it

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check again please. I did not notice the print statement in the block of code.

Comment: I have changed everything you suggested and this was my answer:

Well done <function print_greeting at 0x000001EA0ED5B820>, your average score was 9.0. <function print_teacher_greeting at 0x000001EA0ED5B940> would be proud of you.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check again please. I did not notice that u did not pass the parameters when calling the function in the block of code.

Comment: I would highly recommend you to use `f-string` instead of using `.format`

Comment: It is actually quite difficult to read and edit the code in stackoverflow's text box.

Comment: It finally worked thank you for all of the help!

Comment: No problem! Should have wrapped this up quicker tho...sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `main` function from

```
def main():
  score1, score2, score3, score4 = ask_score()
  determine_outcome(ask_score)
```

to

```
def main():
  for score in ask_score():
    determine_outcome(score)
```

as the way the `ask_score` function is defined, it returns an iterable *(a tuple)* of floats, allowing us to use a `for` loop to pass each float into the `determine_outcome` function individually.

---

Just realized that the `calc_average` function was never called in your code. I believe that the `main` function was supposed to be

```
def main():
  user_score = calc_average(*ask_score())
  determine_outcome(user_score)
```

Comment: I implemented that and I got this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Jammy\Python\main.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Jammy\Python\main.py", line 43, in main
    user_score = calc_average(ask_score())
TypeError: calc_average() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'score2', 'score3', and 'score4'

Comment: Updated *(I missed that `*`)*.

Comment: I tried the updated one and this was the result:

A good effort, <function print_greeting at 0x0000021B0205B820>, your average was <function ask_score at 0x0000021B0205BA60>. <function print_teacher_greeting at 0x0000021B0205B940> thinks you should check your work more carefully.

Comment: Change `print("A good effort, {0}, your average was {1}. {2} thinks you should check your work more carefully.".format(str(print_greeting), str(ask_score), str(print_teacher_greeting)))` to `print("A good effort, {0}, your average was {1}. {2} thinks you should check your work more carefully.".format(greeting, score, greeting))`, and define `greeting` and `score` before them using the corresponding functions. Make sure the functions return the values rather than printing them so that the values can be passed into your formatted string.

Comment: You are making things overly complicated, just returning the str from the `print_greeting` and `print_teacher_greeting` function and using `user_score` instead of `score` in the `determine_outcome` function would do the work.